# unable to run the Log4j2 demo class - While running the class as Java application, Java exception popped out on screen

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, log4j2

This is the demo class I've created to test log4j properties

[image]

Property file is as given
[image]

Please help me to understand why i'm unable to run the Log4j class

Console outut

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No type attribute provided for Appender console
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createAppender(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:216)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.build(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:558)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:322)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:696)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:717)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:272)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at utilities.Log4j.<clinit>(Log4j.java:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing;

appender.console.type = Console

See example here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Yes, after adding the above line, I was able to run the program and also, got the output in console. Thanks! @Erion Omeri.